# function MyClass(){ ... }; MyClass.prototype = MyClass; -- considered harmful?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Apparently it is an idiom in JavaScript to implement class based instance methods this way:

```
function MyClass(){...}
MyClass.prototype.methodA = function(){...}
MyClass.prototype.methodB = function(){...}
...
```

Why aren't people using this less verbose form instead:

```
function MyClass(){...}
MyClass.prototype = MyClass;
MyClass.methodA = function(){...}
MyClass.methodB = function(){...}
```

It obviously does not work if MyClass should inherit from some base class (in that case one should set the prototype to a new instance of the base class typically).

However, deep inheritance hierachies are getting rare these days (thanks to duck typing and mixins among other things).

Am I missing something?

Does MyClass.prototype = MyClass makes .constuctor more a mess than it is already?

Does it interferes in bad ways with typeof, or instanceof, or even getPrototypeOf()?

Should it be promoted, or considered harmful?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because there's an even less verbose form?

```
MyClass.prototype = {
    methodA: function(){},
    methodB: function(){}
};
```

This gets cleaner the more methods you have, other than that, you're just overriding the default prototype and whatever was on it.

Comment: The default prototype is {} I think, maybe with a non enumerable .constructor property pointing to MyClass (I not 100% of that one, I never use it). Not a great loss so far, unless there are use for it that I ignore, suggestions?

Comment: Also, JavaScript has "open classes" so to speak, ie one can add method at any time, you are not obliged to set them up all at the same time or from a unique source file.

Comment: Is the "even less verbose" form that less verbose? If I add up the identation spaces and the , separator, plus the }; terminator... And when navigating large files, I easely get lost, not beeing reminded what is the class I am defining a method for. Readability needs some level of redundancy, where verbosity implies a decrease signal/noise ration.

Comment: Well I only had good experience with this style. `NodeGameShooter.prototype.someFunction` isn't that small either and in case your lines are hitting 80+ columns you should already refactor IMO.

Comment: @JeanHuguesRobert I've done `var fn = MyClass.prototype;` before as an alias. But the more I code the more this felt like a hack and kinda obscures the readability a bit. Especially when a `git grep` drops you on a line far away from the initial `var fn = ...` line. Others have scratched their heads at that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pointless, and it sets you up for potential trouble if one of your methods has a name that obscures a native method from Function.prototype.

You can always initialize the prototype like this:

```
function MyConstructor() { ... }

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  myMethod: function() { ... },
  whatever: null
};
```

*edit* — if you don't like creating object constants (and I have to say that if you're going to be coding in Javascript a lot, I suggest that you try to get used to them), you can just do this:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = {};
MyConstructor.prototype.myMethod = function() { ... };
```

I don't like doing that much typing, personally.

Comment: Yes, that's what I used to do. However the added level indentation, the "," that I some time messed with and the fact that I sometimes inter mix function definitions with meta programming annotation... made me inconfortable with this style (I reverted to the classic .prototype idiom, until I figure out a new solution)

Comment: BTW: I don't get the "potential trouble" you mention, could you elaborate on this? thanks.

Comment: The Function class in Javascript has a bunch of methods on its own prototype object.  If you add methods etc. to your function object, then you won't be able to use those from that instance.  In other words, if you add a method "call" to your prototype, then nothing will be able to do `MyConstructor.call(...)` and get the expected result.

Comment: @Pointy actually, Function.prototype.call() is overridden by MyConstructor.call() (see prototype chain)

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't understand. If I redefine .call(), well, it's probably because I want to turn an instance into a "callable" thing... I understand that, as a side effect, MyClass becomes a callable too, but because MyCall is the prototype of my instance... it is fairly legitimate that it would implement .call() too. Now the question is about MyClass beeing an abstract object or not. With prototype based inheritance, this discution is fairly irrelevant because there is not such thing as a Class in javascript, even less "abstact"